# ¿Cómo hacer una validación?

Tags: java, validación

como puedo validar una contraseña, me piden las siguientes reglas, creo ya implemente algunas pero no se si estén bien.

1. que no sean nulas
2. que tengan una longitud mínima de 6
3. que contengan por lo menos una letra y por lo menos un número
4. que contengan por lo menos una minúscula
5. que contengan por lo menos una mayúscula
6. puede contener letras dígitos ‘-’, ‘_’ , ‘,’ , ’:’, ‘;’, y ‘.’

Si mi código esta correcto solo me faltaría la regla 6, que es la que no tengo idea de como validarla

```
public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
     if (contraseña==null){
        // no debe ser nulo
        return;
    }
     if (contraseña.length()<6){
        // su longitud minima es de 6
        return;
    }
     if (!contraseña.contains("[A-Z]")){
        // debe contener mayusculas
        return;
     }
     if (!contraseña.contains("[a-z]")){
        // debe contener minusculas
        return;
     }
     if (!contraseña.contains("[0-9]")){
         // debe contener numeros
        return;
     }
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}
```

Comment: Usa expresiones regulares para la captura de tu contraseña

Answer (score 3):

para este tipo de situaciones es siempre mejor utilizar Expresiones Regulares, sería bueno que investigue sobre el tema te va ayudar mucho, ahora para tu ejemplo completo puede hacer lo siguiente

```
public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{6,20}$");
     Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(contraseña);                                                                           
     if (mat.matches()) {
         this.contraseña = contraseña;
     } else {
         return;                                                                              
     }
}
```

en este ejemplo permito los símbolos pero no son obligatorios de ser así necesita un cambio, con esta expresion regular puse el mínimo 6 y el máximo 20 eso puede cambiarlo a gusto, una cosa que es personal pero bueno, no me gusta usar return para nada en un método void creo que pejor debe hacer una función que valide la contraseña y devuelve verdadero o falso y en base a eso sette la contraseña o no,

Saludos