# Validar contraseña punto a punto Java

Tags: java, regex, validación

intento validar una contraseña con Java, pero solo he encontrado expresiones regulares y no logro identificar cual de los pasos en la expresión regular no se cumple.

Quiero por ejemplo la siguiente política:

- Tener mínimo 8 caracteres
- Tener al menos un carácter minúscula (a-z)
- Tener al menos un carácter Mayúscula (A-Z)
- Tener al menos un numero (0-9)
- No permitir caracteres especiales
- No permitir espacios

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```java
TextInputLayout fieldPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPasswordSignup);

private boolean validatePassword(){
        String password = fieldPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(password);

        if(password.isEmpty() || password ==""){
            fieldPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
            fieldPassword.setError("Este campo no puede estar vacío.");
            return false;
        }else if(!matcher.matches()){
            fieldPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
            fieldPassword.setError("Contraseña no válida, modifica e intenta nuevamente.");
            return false;
        }
        fieldPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        fieldPassword.setError("");
        return true;
    }
```

Quiero por ejemplo dividir, no se, si es con arreglos o como hacer para que en caso que no se cumpla alguna de las condiciones de la expresión regular, poder agregar un texto en  `.setError("")`, como por ejemplo.  `.setError("Escriba al menos una letra mayúscula")`.

De la forma en que tengo mi código, solo puedo decir que la contraseña no es válida, pero no puedo decir el porque, no se cual de las condiciones no se cumple.

Deseo hacer hacer lo mismo con el correo electrónico, les agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482539/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-validaci%c3%b3n), sólo cambia el `\w`

Comment: @EduardoJiménez muchas gracias, tu comentario me sirvió para validar completamente la contraseña, sin embargo no logré mostrar al usuario que parte de la contraseña era incorrecta, pues no se como recorrer la expresión regular para ver cual no se cumple. En todos modos muchas gracias.

Comment: La verdad no sabría cómo extraer qué parte del regex no coincide, otra solución sería que evalúes por partes (cada condición)

Answer (score 3):

Para lo que mencionas algo que podrías usar es usar el patrón de diseño Composite.

En su definición nos indica que consiste en componer estructuras arbóreas para representar jerarquías parte-todo. El Composite le permite a los clientes el tratar a los objetos individuales y a las composiciones de objetos uniformemente.

Es decir, la idea es poderle aplicar a un texto tanto validaciones simples como validaciones compuestas o derivadas de otras validaciones, para tu caso en particular te recomiendo aplicarlo más o menos de esta manera:

[image: Validador compuesto a partir de validadores individuales]

Ahora si tuvieras un caso muchísimo más complejo, podrías modificar el validador compuesto para que a su vez fuera un validador al implementar dicha interfaz.

Código fuente del diagrama:

```
@startuml
interface Validador<Tipo>{
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorTamanio implements Validador {
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorTieneMayuscula implements Validador {
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorTieneMinuscula implements Validador {
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorSinSimbolo implements Validador {
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorSinEspacios implements Validador {
  +boolean esValido(Tipo objetivo)
  +Optional<String> mensajeDeError()
}

class ValidadorCompuesto{
 -Collection<Validador> validaciones
 +boolean cumpleTodasValidaciones()
 +List<String> obtenMensajesDeError()
 +void agregarValidacion()
 +void quitarValidacion()
}

ValidadorCompuesto ..> "1..*" Validador
@enduml
```

En este caso el `ValidadorCompuesto`, simplemente es una clase donde tienes:

- una colección como una lista con todas las validaciones sencillas a hacer.
- Un método para ejecutar una validación tras otra encadenadas de la lista que tenías.
- una colección como una lista para almacenar los mensajes de error que salgan en cada validación sencilla
- un método para obtener todos los mensajes de error que hubieran salido en caso de que no pasaran todas las validaciones sencillas

Comment: Amigo, gracias por tu respuesta, sin duda quizás si funciona, en mi caso, aun estoy en proceso de aprendizaje, por ende no logré comprender la lógica  del validador compuesto.

Comment: he agregado una pequeña explicación de para que sirve cada cosa en el validador compuesto

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por tu explicación. Profundizaré un poco mas en el tema de colecciones. Gracias por tu apoyo.